# componente devexpress para memorizar edit

Tags: delphi, devexpress

Alguém sabe qual componente do devexpress (delphi) que faz com que memorizar o texto editado nos edit(s) da aplicação ?

exemplo: tenho um TEdit, com nome de usuario, depois que digitar pela primeira vez, quando for digitar na segunda vez assim que colocar a primeira letra ele ja reconhece o que tinha digitado anteriormente (claro se tiver com a mesma letra do inicio.)

Answer (score 2):

Na verdade é uma propriedade presente em diversos componentes que aceitam textos, como Edit e ComboBox, por exemplo. Na documentação procure por MRU (Most Recently Used / Mais Recentemente Utilizados).
Explorando a propriedade MRUList dos componentes você verá que é possível gravar e recuperar os valores automaticamente.

Exemplo em WinForms.
https://documentation.devexpress.com/WindowsForms/DevExpress.XtraEditors.MRUEdit.members

Comment: Embora este link possa responder à pergunta, é melhor incluir as partes essenciais da resposta aqui e fornecer o link para referência.  As respostas apenas por link podem ser invalidadas se a página com o link for alterada. - [Da Revisão](/review/low-quality-posts/178121)

Comment: @RBZ, o link que postei não responde a pergunta, até porque trata-se de Visual Studio, enquanto a pergunta trata-se de Delphi, o que quis foi passar o conceito para facilitar a implementação. "MRUList" é a reposta para a pergunta, é apenas uma propriedade e não necessariamente precisa de códigos adicionais, mas isso abre um leque de outras possíveis perguntas que não poderiam ser respondidas aqui. ;-)

Comment: Marcio, vou te explicar o porque marquei isso na revisão. Eu não conheço delphi, então eu tenho que em parte deduzir que você está explicando certo, correto!? Então você diz "Na documentação procure por MRU"... Nisso, você já poderia ter passado essa documentação referente ao o que o usuário precisa, e melhor explicando, dar um exemplo, trazer mais informações, entende!? Novamente ficou no ar "Explorando a propriedade MRUList dos componentes..." incremente com exemplos, mesmo que sejam simples... poderá outro usuário vir até essa pergunta, sabendo menos ainda... entendeu?...

Comment: Não que sua resposta esteja incorreta só por link, mas eu poderia ter marcado como "Deveria ser um comentário" também... entendeu!? ;)

Comment: Tranquilo, é que a documentação da DevExpress é um arquivo CHM (ou PDF) gigantesco (só a parte que trata de editores tem mais de 5 mil páginas) que fica instalado junto do componente (não há versão online para VCL), e não tenho a DevExpress instalada na minha IDE. De qualquer forma hoje a noite instalo e preparo um exemplo com imagens, aí atualizo minha resposta.